# JavaScript Array creates empty element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```js
var arr = [];
console.log(arr);
console.log("Length: " + arr.length);
arr[1] = [{},{}];
console.log(arr);
console.log("Length: " + arr.length);
arr[3] = [{},{}];
console.log(arr);
console.log("Length: " + arr.length);
```

So when I create an array like above it gives empty/undefined elements in between.

I want to remove those empty/undefined elements while preserving the index values.

```
vm.eArray = vm.eArray.filter(function (arr) {
    return arr.length;
});
```

I'm using the above code to remove the undefined elements but it messes my index/key values.

Or is there any way to avoid it at first place?

Comment: Why are you inserting element to array[1] where there is no value in array[0]?

Comment: Arrays are 0 indexed I think this is being overlooked... facepalm moment for sure :)

Comment: What you are looking for is called a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: @edkeveked i want to store id's in index.

Comment: @shaunhusain i know arrays are 0 indexed.

Comment: @KeyurShah, I guess, if you want to store id's value, the best way is to use whether a map (and then you can iterate over them), or to use a Json object (but you cannot iterate over it unless you provide your own constructor)

Comment: @KeyurShah see what Derek said/linked you want to use a Map or an object as a map it sounds like.  Arrays should just be used for lists the length only really makes sense when you have a flat list otherwise look to other data structures.  An array has a start pointer and an offset if you are leaving huge gaps in the array for empty offsets it no longer really makes sense as a data structure for the problem.

Comment: @edkeveked Can you give an example?

Comment: Use an object to store key-value pair. But key in index is string.

Comment: @KeyurShah, you can see my working snippet below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array are an index data structure. So when using them, it is better to keep that structure otherwise there is no use to use an array. For your use case, you can use whether a Map(), or an array of Json element.

- Using a Map, your indexes (1, 2, 3) can become directly the keys of your array.
- Another solution could be to use an array of Json element, where each element has a key and a value

```js
var myMap = new Map();
//to add the element with index 1
myMap.set(1, [{},{}]);

//to add the element with index 3
myMap.set(3, [{},{}]);

// you can iterate over them if you want like an array
console.log("with a map")
myMap.forEach((key, value) => console.log(key, value));

// using a Json object

var myObject = [];
myObject.push({id: 1, value:[{},{}]})
myObject.push({id: 3, value:[{},{}]})

//iterate over it, because it is still an array, but of Json element
console.log("with array of json")
for (element of myObject){
  console.log(element.id, element.value)
}
```

Comment: I have used Json object. Thanks for your efforts. Now i understand the use of map as well

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = new Map();
console.log(arr);
console.log("Length: " + arr.size);
arr.set(1,[{},{}]);
console.log(arr);
console.log("Length: " + arr.size);
arr.set(3,[{},{}]);
console.log(arr);
console.log("Length: " + arr.size);
```

You can use `Map()`, and get the size using `map.size`.

Comment: can i use angular.forEach or ng-repeat on map? or

Comment: I was on that same page. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I would just use an object to store your values.

```
    var arr = {};
    console.log(arr);
    console.log("Length: " + Object.keys(arr).length);
    arr[1] = [{},{}];
    console.log(arr);
    console.log("Length: " + Object.keys(arr).length);
    arr[3] = [{},{}];
    console.log(arr);
    console.log("Length: " + Object.keys(arr).length);

    for (something in arr){
      console.log(arr[something]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value `arr[1] = arr[1] = [{},{}];` at index 1. So you are skipping index 0. By default, javascript will place `undefined` there.